# Max OSX Swift App perform tasks with elevated rights

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, applescript, sudo

I built an windows app that runs exe's, scripts, bat files everything. For that i have started a service with system account to perform tasks that need admin rights.

I need to replicate same for mac. I have never done development on mac, did some research and found out best way is to make swift cocoa app for OSX in xcode. I am able to perform admin tasks in mac using shell script, python, apple script. But however if try to call the same bash, python script from the cocoa app it doesn't work. It turns out i cannot do anything that need elevated rights from my swift cocoa app because of sandboxing concept mac apps use.

Is there any way out? Is there any other technology i need to use for my requirements? Is there a way to perform tasks that need elevated rights from mac app? Please guide.

Comment: A quick answer is nope.

Comment: @ElTomato can u please elaborate. can app be made without sandbox ? i know sandboxing is mandatory to publish, but i need to use app locally and not publish it out for the world.

Comment: yes of course. an app can be created without sandboxing. It will not pass gatekeeper then and you have to explicitly allow execution but of course. it can be done. it's even easier than with sandboxing

Comment: @Pat_Morita Thanks for the reply. I removed the sandboxing and was able to do tasks with elevated rights. However, as u mentioned we would need to explicitly allow execution for gatekeeper, this might be an issue security wise to run on other machines. Is there any other possible way to do such tasks using OSX internal apis via swift code similar to those available in windows. If yes, can u share a link for it. Thanks